# Robocraft problem loading assets Arch Linux

Tags: linux, robocraft

Starting the game on Arch Linux (64 bit) directly, using Steam to download it (but not run it, ELFCLASS errors because I'm 64 bit)
(So running `$HOME/.local/share/Steam/SteamApps/common/Robocraft/Robocraft.x86`)

I get errors loading unity3d assets. Specifically:

`Error loading the game files from your H.D. 
Extra Info: Error downloading:`

Before yesterday's update, the complaint was re:
`~/.local/share/Steam/SteamApps/common/Robocraft/assetbundles/6be135163de3e3a48bf796c355b358d7face_left_col_fbx.unity3d`

Today the complaint is re: `~/.local/share/Steam/SteamApps/common/Robocraft/assetbundles/08d23fc4d17333f4c9881ea1b9d159baRC_Mars_Planet_Sphere_fbx.unity3d`

Comment: I have the same problem here on Fedora. Are you running on a laptop with Bumblebee by any chance? Because I do and I wonder whether this is an issue.

Comment: Running a laptop, no Bumblebee.